# Flickering while moving an image from right to left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am moving an image from right to left by changing the imageView center. I am using a NSTimer to trigger the event of changing the center. Everything is working fine except that the image movement is not smooth and is flickering. Kindly help.

Comment: Try giving appropriate animation to `UIImageView`

Answer (score 1):

hm,... but you do use the QuartzCore Framework to animate the movement don't you?
Like in

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // animation duration in seconds
image.center = view.center;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Don't you?
Oh and make sure that you're on the main-thread. GUI-Handling on other Threads can produce stuff you don't want ;)

Comment: no, i just used NSTimer to trigger a method where i am simply changing the imageView center by 1px

Answer (score 0):

```
        Try this code animation flip right to left its definitely help u.

        #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // animation duration in seconds
        image.center = view.center;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```